# Error on ORACLE trigger

Tags: oracle, triggers, oracle10g, toad

I have this sexy trigger, that takes a value from a field REFERENT, parses it, finds a row in some view and fills some data to original row that needs to be inserted. I also then re-write the REFERENT field and eliminate the extra data.

The REFERENT field looks like this: "-XXX-123", where 123 is the key that i search data in the view. Hope it makes sense.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER TRI_UPDATE
BEFORE INSERT
ON TBLASCENTOUTPUT_X
REFERENCING NEW AS NEW OLD AS OLD
FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (
new.STEVILKA_NAROCILA is NULL
      )
DECLARE
    PARSED_STNAROC   VARCHAR(255);
    PARSED_PRIMARY_VALUE VARCHAR(255);
BEGIN

    PARSED_STNAROC := SUBSTR(NEW.REFERENT, INSTR(NEW.REFERENT, '-', -1, 1) + 1);
    PARSED_PRIMARY_VALUE := SUBSTR(NEW.REFERENT, 1, INSTR(NEW.REFERENT, '-', -1, 1) - 1);

    select distinct v.STNAROCILA, v.DATNAROCILA, v.SIFKUPCA, v.STPONUDBE, PARSED_PRIMARY_VALUE 
        into  :NEW.STEVILKA_NAROCILA, :NEW.DATUM_NAROCILA, :NEW.SIFRA_KUPCA, :NEW.STEVILKA_PONUDBE, :NEW.REFERENT
        from ARH_NAROC v
        where v.STNAROCILA = PARSED_STNAROC;

END;
```

I am getting the following error on compile:

```
On line:  6
TRIGGER EASY.TRI_UPDATE
PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.REFERENT' must be declared
```

Help please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A colon character is missed before `NEW.REFERENT`

Comment: Thanks a lot 8 years later but somebody still finding this answer really helpful